# wordpress advanced custom fields select values

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm working with Wordpress 3.5.2 and plugin Advanced CUstom Fields 4.1.8

I have a group of fields (called "P") and some fields.
I want to retreive all data from a specific select field, and I found some code in the plugin documentation:

$values = get_field('field_519a0279bc93e');
if($values)
{

```
foreach($values as $value)
{
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

}

In $values, getting two different select fields In a case I get a string and in another a boolean. 
I supposed is so simple, but I can't find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have experience in Advanced Custom Fields but don't quite understand your question. Are you simply trying to output the values for the specified custom field?

Comment: Yes, only the values inserted as options in the select field: "male", "female".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so in the admin, the custom field specifies one of 2 values. Male or female. I'm guessing on the front end it will say something like sex: male is that right? If so I'll post a suggestion

Comment: Yes. The result of "echo $values;" shows: "Male", only one value, and not an array with the two values, as it says in the plugin documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that when using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin all this does is create an easier method for admins to add custom fields for posts, so the WordPress [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) still applies.

Say you've created a custom field called 'sex' and you've assigned a dropdown or radio buttons to it and you wanted to display what this value in the post or the loop, you would do the following.

**Outside the loop**

```
 ## Returns sex custom field value for current page ID
 $sex = get_post_meta( get_the_ID, 'sex', true);
```

**Inside the loop**

```
## Returns sex custom field value for current loop iteration
global $post;
$sex = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sex', true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does'nt work for me.
I search in the api.php acf plugin, and there I've found what I want:

`$field = get_field_object('field_519a0279bc93e', false, $options = array() );
$values = $field["choices"];
foreach($values as $value)
{
    echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';`

Thanks @JoeBuckle